# Cross domain tracking

Tags: google-analytics, cross-domain

I set up the cross domain but I have a problem, GA doesn't link the visit on the site1 with the site on the site2. Actually the user arrives to the site1 by facebook ads and makes a lead generation, and then, by a dem, arrives to site2 and makes the conversion.
I can see the lead generation and the conversion but GA doesn't link the two sessions so I can't see the first touch point of the final conversion. 
Should I set up something about ID user?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on the site for [professional webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com)

Comment: You need to provide a little more info, namely how your tracking code looks. Userid will not help you with cross domain tracking, more likely the "linker", the thing that adds the url parameter that is added for cross domain tracking is not configured correctly (or the receiving side has a serverside redirect that cuts off the  liker parameter). Can you post a few details ?

Comment: The cross domain is setting by the plugin monsterinsight for Wordpress. I put just this part of code - __gaTracker('require', 'linker');
 __gaTracker('linker:autoLink', ['example-2.com', 'example-3.com'] ); - into the plugin